How can I access API from 1fitcher through Jdownload?
I am working on a Java program that needs to use 1fitchers API through Jdownloader. I need an API key from 1fitcher. However, I came across the following instructions from the JDownloader knowledge base:
Jdownloader devs website

For free 1fichier accounts:
Open JDownloader -> Settings -> Plugins -> 1fichier.com -> Disable
"Use premium API." Add your free 1fichier account in Settings ->
Account Manager -> Add -> 1fichier.com -> Enter your username and
password.

And according to: Jdownloader website
This is a common issue. I'm a Java developer, and currently, I want to implement file uploading into my application. Now I need to use 1fichier's API. Can this API be available just with a premium account, or does JDownloader assist me in using APIs or act like a download manager? Your suggestions are welcome with regards to access to API or/and creating a premium account. I don't want to do anything unethical but my current code solution is best with this API. Is this possible and if so why and what does premium entail? This confuses me. This seems like an odd limbo zone but if it is not a way around the premium access which one must pay for then what is Jdownloader doing?

I really want to know what this is and if it allows access to the API of 1f b.c. then that is cool and there is potential to have a really good program for random users with respect to data. I wonder what the limitations are?
